# How to send a Word document to an email (PHP, Javascript)?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm developing a site for a small business and I have a request where they want to allow people to submit their CV's. Therefore I need to allow a user to choose their CV and then click Send which sends the file to an email address.

I'm fairly new to web programming. Is this easy? I know PHP and a little javascript, would that be enough? I've looked around the web but have found many different answers and mostly about uploading to servers and not to emails.

Greatly appreciated!!  I'm still learning   :)

Comment: You will need to upload to the server first, then attach to the e-mail (then delete the file afterwards if you like).

Comment: The process would go like this: Upload the file to your server. Use your server-side language to mail the file to whoever it needs to go too. You need to be very careful with this though. If a spammer were to gain unrestricted to access to this system, they could use it to send malware email spam out through your SMTP server.

Comment: How long have you been using PHP?

Comment: @crush, is there a way to add protection against a spammer?

Comment: There are many techniques that have to be employed. Probably the best way is to only offer the email form/file upload to users who have authenticated with your site. The other option is to not allow the "to" field of the email to be specified via the email form (hidden form fields aren't enough - don't put this in your HTML at all). This prevents spam bots from sending the email to anyone they choose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Massimino,

Irrespective of spamming and security issues & file types, here's a rough algorithm / workflow to follow which highlights the key features:

**Step #1) Create your basic HTML Form pattern:** 
a) The form should be of type METHOD=POST method with an ACTION="[your-php-script]" 
b) An **input field of type="file"** ( this allows you to select a file for uploading from your respective client os)

**note:** [your-php-script] refers to the actual php file which contains the application functionality for the server backend to accomplish your above task. (ie. "yourfile.php")

**Step #2**) **In your php script** you should perform the following:

**a) Get the actual file name** of the file just submitted by your user "Usually you will need to consult the global php array "$_FILES" for this info.

**note:** You can also obtain the file size and file extenstion in the event you would like to perform some additional filtering and /or validation.

**b) (Optional) Perform any validation** and/or filtering (ie. no windows exes ect.)

**c) Save the file on your server.** Copy from a temporary initial store to a server directory of your choosing.

d)   **Compose and send the Email with the File as an attachment**.
The easiest way to do  this is using the **php "PEAR" Library**

**Note:** check with your hosting provider to see if they have uploaded this php module.

To fill in the actual details (ie implementation) from the above high level steps of the algorithm. I've found the following article helpful in [html form guide](http://www.html-form-guide.com/email-form/php-email-form-attachment.html).

regards,
Scott

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend forcing users to upload their CV as a PDF, this would make your life a lot easier from a security and integrity perspective. With this you and your clients would have the safeguarding that the document will not easily be modified.

Here is some example code using PHPMailer

```
<?php

require_once('../class.phpmailer.php');

$mail             = new PHPMailer(); // defaults to using php "mail()"

$body             = file_get_contents('contents.html');
$body             = eregi_replace("[\]",'',$body);

$mail->AddReplyTo("name@yourdomain.com","First Last");

$mail->SetFrom('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');

$mail->AddReplyTo("name@yourdomain.com","First Last");

$address = "whoto@otherdomain.com";
$mail->AddAddress($address, "John Doe");

$mail->Subject    = "PHPMailer Test Subject via mail(), basic";

$mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test

$mail->MsgHTML($body);

$mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer.gif");      // attachment
$mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer_mini.gif"); // attachment

if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo "Message sent!";
}

?>
```

https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer

Comment: Why does a PDF make it easier than, e.g. a DOCX? Your answer doesn't seem to answer this assertion. In fact, you're sending GIF in your example.

Comment: It's also not the best when it comes to being user friendly.

Comment: With PHPMailer it makes no difference, sorry you can define allowed document types. $allowedExts = array("doc", "docx", "pdf");

Comment: PDF files are standard worldwide and reduce user intervention and modifications to safeguard data etc. All fixed documentation should be PDF'd to ensure trust from clients and trust from staff. This is my personal opinion from working in a sector governed by standard and security.

Comment: MS Office, Open Office and other free office suites now offer EXPORT to PDF options. I work in a company full of students of young ages who are all educated to submit any documentation as PDF's for this reason.

Comment: PDF documents can contain viruses and malicious code that exploits vulnerabilities in PDF viewing software (such as Adobe Reader). I'm not sure they are much more secure than a Word document. They are certainly more *portable*.

Comment: Crush, this is a mute point. A DOCX/DOC can contain macros and VB Scripts which also could be offensive or destructive.